# Does "reset" require "shift" inside the block?

Tags: scala, continuations

Is it correct that `reset` requires `shift` inside the block?  I tried it and got the following:

```
scala> reset {} 
error: cannot cps-transform expression (): type arguments [Unit,Unit,Nothing]
do not conform to method shiftUnit's type parameter bounds [A,B,C >: B]
```

It looks reasonable (since `reset` block without `shift` inside is "dead code", which is never executed)  but I do not understand the error.

What is the exact meaning of the error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't agree, that code within `reset` is dead without `shift`. Actually `reset` just defines the boundaries of a continuation (that's because they are called **delimited** continuations).The code would be dead if you have `shift` somewhere within `reset` and you do not call continuation function. For example:

```
reset {
  println(1)
  shift((k: Unit => Unit) => println(2))
  println(3)
}
```

The code after `shift` is dead (`println(3)`) because I have not called `k(Unit)`.

From the other hand, seems that `reset` expects some special return type from it's body - the one that annotated with `@cpsParam` annotation. You can check definition of `reset` method:

```
def reset[A,C](ctx: => (A @cpsParam[A,C])): C = ...
```

And `shift` produces just what `reset` method expects. Here is definition of `shift` method:

```
def shift[A,B,C](fun: (A => B) => C): A @cpsParam[B,C] = ...
```

But you still can use `reset` without `shift` call within it. This trick will do it:

```
def foo[T](body: => T @cps[Any]) = reset(body)

foo {
  println("it works")
}
```

Please note, that `@cps` is just type alias for `@cpsParam`. Here it's definition:

```
type cps[A] = cpsParam[A, A]
```